# Grid columns are not aligning across containers

Tags: css, css-grid

I want a way to make all the gaps align and the elements with size `2fr` to have the same width in both grids.

One grid has 2 columns with a gap of 30px. Inside of the first column there are 2 child columns with gap of 30px.

The second grid has 3 columns with gap of 30px as well.

I want the gap of the children of the first column to align with the gap of the second grid.

Is there a way I can do this?

I have tried with no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kvog14mc/38/)

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.grid-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(240px, auto);
  gap: 30px;
}

.grid-1-2-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(240px, auto);
  gap: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  gap: 30px;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.grid-2x2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  gap: 30px;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.child {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid-2">
    <div class="grid-2x2">
      <div class="child">one</div>
      <div class="child">two</div>
      <div class="child">three</div>
      <div class="child">four</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">five</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid-1-2-1">
    <div class="grid-1">
      <div class="child">one</div>
      <div class="child">two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">tree</div>
    <div class="child">four</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't align the columns using `fr` units in two different containers based on your code.

You'll need to combine the grid items into the same container, used fixed widths or something else. But with differing `fr` units—which are not a length but only distribute free space—it won't work across multiple containers.

It's the math.

Here's what's happening:

---

### Container #1 – Primary Container

The first primary container has two columns set to `1fr`.

```
.grid-2 {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
   gap: 30px;
}
```

There is one 30px gap in the container.

For clarity, let's switch the width of the container from the viewport width (which is flexible) to a fixed 1000px.

So the free space in this container is:

```
1000px - 30px = 970px
```

Hence, each `1fr` column will be 485px wide:

```
970px / 2 = 485px
```

This checks out.

[image]

[image]

---

### Container #1 – Nested Container

Within column one of the primary container there's a nested grid, also with two columns.

```
.grid-2x2 {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
   gap: 30px;
}
```

This container also has one 30px gap.

So here's the math on this container:

```
485px - 30px = 455px free space

455px / 2 = 227.5px width of each column
```

This also checks out.

[image]

[image]

---

### Container #2 – Primary Container

The second primary container has three columns set to `1fr 2fr 1fr`.

```
.grid-1-2-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  gap: 30px;
}
```

There are **two** 30px gaps in this container.

Again, using `width: 1000px` for demo purposes, the free space in this container is:

```
1000px - 60px = 940px
```

Hence, each `1fr` column will be 235px wide:

```
940px / 4 = 235px
```

This checks out.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

I think we can stop here.

As you can see, because of the math involving the gaps and the differing distributions of free space:

- the first column in the first container has a width of 227.50px, and
- the first column in the second container has a width of 235px.

Comment: This would be a good use case for subgrid, when it is fully available.